# Function writing data to a spreadsheet

Tags: go

The code below works as intended: write data by iterating over columns, while iterating over rows while iterating over sheets.

```
func createXlSXFile(sheets []Sheet) (*bytes.Buffer, error) {
    file := excelize.NewFile()
    file.SetSheetName("Sheet1", sheets[0].Title)
    defer func() {
            if err := file.Close(); err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
            }
    }()

    for i := range sheets {
            if 0 != i {
                    s, _ := file.NewSheet(sheets[i].Title)
                    file.SetActiveSheet(s)
            }
            for j := range sheets[i].Columns {
                    cellName, _ := excelize.CoordinatesToCellName(j+1, 1)
                    file.SetCellValue(
                            sheets[i].Title,
                            cellName,
                            sheets[i].Columns[j].Title,
                    )
            }

            for j := range sheets[i].Dataset {
                    for k := range sheets[i].Columns {
                            cellName, _ := excelize.CoordinatesToCellName(k+1, j+2)
                            file.SetCellValue(
                                    sheets[i].Title,
                                    cellName,
                                    sheets[i].Columns[k].Getter(*(sheets[i].Dataset[j])),
                            )
                    }
            }
    }

    return file.WriteToBuffer()
}
```

In order for the function above to be independent of any input-type, the `Sheet` type is defined as follows:

```
type Sheet struct {
    Title   string
    Columns []Column
    Dataset []*any
}
type Column struct {
    Title  string
    Getter func(any) string
}
```

Example of usage:

```
sheets := []Sheet{
    {
        Title:   "Production Tenants",
        Dataset: prodTenants,
        Columns: []Column{
            {
                Title: "Tenant Name",
                Getter: func(t any) string {
                    tnnt, ok := t.(Tenant)
                    if !ok {
                        return "TYPE ASSERTION FAILED"
                    }
                    return tnnt.Name()
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        Title: "Production Accounts",
        Dataset: prodAccounts,
        Columns: []Column{
            {
                Title: "Account ID",
                Getter: func(t any) string {
                    acc, ok := t.(Account)
                    if !ok {
                        return "TYPE ASSERTION FAILED"
                    }
                    return acc.ID()
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

result, _ := createXlSXFile(sheets)
```

The issue with this implementation is:

1. For every Sheet, in order to create the a `dataset`, I need to iterate over the actual data-variables and wrap them into interface-variables.
2. For every `Getter` function, I need to assert a type.

Another possible implementation I can explore is to create a type-dependent create-sheet function and then append the sheets into a single document.

Is there a better way or a more GO-idiomatic way to implement the above functionality?